# Freezes when finishing installation of ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, freeze

I wanted to install **Ubuntu next to my Windows 7** and made a 100GB partition for that. After that I downloaded the Image for burning the installation cd. As soon as I started to boot from that **DVD**, my computer made some **crackling noises** and then **froze completely**. I had to press the power button in order to shut it down.

After that I decided to download the **Installer Version** for Windows and startet installing it on the `E:\` partition named Ubuntu. So far so good, the installer finished and told me to restart my computer. I did that and Ubuntu wanted to finish the installation. As soon as that started, the computer made some crackling noises again and froze completely.

Then I tried the **Safe Graphics** option, or whatever it is called, and it froze again. 
I would really like to have Ubuntu installed on my system, because I like it. My computer components are the following:

- Mainboard: Gigabyte X58-USB3
- Processor: Intel Core i7 960
- RAM: 8GB 2000Mhz
- Graphicscard: NVidia Geforce GTX 570
- HDD: 1 TB 7200rpm with 3 partitions(100GB W7, 100GB Ubuntu, 800GB Data)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be nice to know where exacly your boot fails:
During BIOS hold down  <kbd>shift</kbd> until Grub appears, edit the kernel parameters (the line that starts with `linux`) by removing the `quiet splash $vt_handoff` and then boot by hitting <kbd>F10</kbd>.
Maybe the output shows where the system stalls. You should post the results.

I have kind of the same problem, although on an notebook with a NVS 4200M. I found the culprit is the graphics card driver that comes with the Ubuntu distribution (nouveau). Partially I am able to boot to Ubuntu by editing the kernel parameters to `ro nomodeset noplymouth`. Maybe this helps you although in my case the fix only worked once.

Once you have access to a terminal, you might want to remove the nouveau driver and/or blacklist it and then install the proprietary nvidia driver by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

or use this link:
[image: Install via the software center]

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried everything you suggested and I came up with the following:
I edited the kernel parameters, but I only deleted "quiet splash" because there was no "$vt_handoff". Anyway, [this](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3077/4kc7zobo_jpg.htm) is as far as I came, until it froze again. I tried it once more and came to [this](http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3077/tiddvycb_jpg.htm). 

Trying to edit the parameters to "ro nomodeset noplymouth" resulted in the same thing as seen in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

i had the exact same problem with the 12.04 and 12.10 desktop and an nvidia card.  i was not able to get past the login screen without it hard-freezing the whole machine.  this appears to be a widespread problem with ubuntu 12 desktop installations and nvidia cards.

fwiw, i was able to get up and running by installing the ubuntu 12.10 **server** edition that comes with **no drivers or desktop** (you don't have to install any of the actual server components like lamp or tomcat).  then, with the luxury of a working console:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

...after installation, launch the desktop with

```
startx
```

...and tada, you've got a beautiful new desktop.  the last hurdle was that after rebooting, i was stuck in 640x480 resolution.  there are a number of different suggestions to fix this if you search around - they all have to do with editing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.  the one that i tried, which worked, was to change the HorizSync and VertRefresh values as suggested here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1659556

...and that's all i had to do to get a stable, hi-res ubuntu 12.10 desktop working with an nvidia card.

from reading around, it sounds like the problem may have been due to bad interaction between the nouveau video driver that comes with the desktop version by default, and the unity desktop that also is the desktop default.  i can't offer any useful debugging info, all i know is that by completely avoiding the default drivers and the unity desktop i was able to get up and running with no problem.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

given that the problem arises as soon as you try to boot from the DVD it seems the problem is the DVD is faulty maybe it's not properly burned, sometimes it happens specially on faster burn speeds. I would try burning another DVD or I personally recommend using a USB boot, see if that works

Comment: So I basically tried anything you've said. I tried booting from a USB Stick and I even burned a second DVD, but the same thing still happens. Freezes everywhere! Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: no sorry, I don't know enough, hopefully someone more experienced will help